# Python Praw TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python-3.x, praw

I wasn't getting this message when I was running the script earlier...and now I am. What am I missing?

```
comments.reply("__%s__","\n","Current Temp: %s\u00b0F" % (str(cityname),temp_f))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the third string:

```
"Current Temp: %s\u00b0F" % (str(cityname),temp_f)
```

It contains only one format specifier `%s` but a 2-tuple as formatting arguments. Hence not all arguments can be converted during the formatting. On the other hand your first string `__%s__` goes unformatted, so I have the feeling that you rather want do combine these three strings either (e.g. by leaving out the commas):

```
comments.reply("__%s__\nCurrent Temp: %s\u00b0F" % (cityname, temp_f))
```